# Android animation not working properly - doesn't play, want it to stop when sound file stops

Tags: android, animation, audio

Current Outcome: When the img button is pressed it plays a sound file but does not do the animation.

Desired Outcome: When the img button is pressed, it plays a sound file and does the animation, when the sound file is done playing, the animation stops.

Problem: I'm trying to write the logic for this and my log statements tell me it should be working as I see "animation start" and "animation stop". Odd thing is, my img button changes color when pressed which is good, but it stays that color until the sound file is done, as if it's in a constant pressed state until sound is finished. Am I completely missing something? Any ideas?

StartActivity;

```
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                soundClassObject.setMP(getApplicationContext());
                soundClassObject.checkSound2(imgButton,animation1);
            }
        });
```

Sound Class;

```
public void setMP(Context c){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(c, returnRandomSound());
    }

public void checkSound2(View v, Animation a){
        v.startAnimation(a);
        mp.start();
        Log.i(TAG, "Animation start: " + v.getAnimation());
      while(v.getAnimation() != null) {
          stopAnimation(v);
      }
    }

public void stopAnimation(View v){
    if (!mp.isPlaying()){
        v.clearAnimation();
        Log.i(TAG, "Animation stopped: " + v.getAnimation());
    }
}
```

Animation;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="100"
android:fromDegrees="-5"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a MediaPlayer listener to my method -

```
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    v.clearAnimation();
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.imgbutton1:
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boat);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imgbutton2:
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.train);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imgbutton3:
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket);
                            break;
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "v animation clear: " + v.getAnimation());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Later mp: " + mp.getAudioSessionId());
                }

            });
```